# How get the current device audio stream routing on Android?

Tags: android, audio, routes, device

Due to some **deprecated API**, I'm looking for code to know which device is **routing current audio Stream**. I can list all devices, know if the headset is connected but the API says connected but not routing. Now, I want to check, **how to check which one is routing audio at this time.**

I found in documentation but don't know how to use: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRouting.html
Any ideas?